# How to create a report in VSTS that collates work item descriptions/resolutions for easy readability?

Tags: azure-devops, manual-testing

In VSTS a tester wants to be able to select or identify a Work Item and automatically produce a consolidated view of the Description and Resolution fields of the selected Work Item **and related Work Items**.  The output would be well formatted for readability maybe like the Test Case Export.

I can write a query but:
1. The output is not well formatted for readability
2. One has to edit the query at each use to input the currently desired Work Item

All reporting documentation seems focused on metrics.  Here I want just a pretty text document.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below ways to export the work items and see the `Description` or `Resolution` text document:

- The best document format is viewing the `Description` or `Resolution`
  **within** VSTS:

  Create a query first, then view the work items one by one :

  [image]
- Create a query, `Email...` or `Copy as HTML`, but the text is not
  well formatted.

  [image]
- Install and use the extension : [Enhanced Export](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mskold.mskold-enhanced-export&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.vssps.visualstudio.com%2F_signedin%3Frealm), but seems it
  can only export and format part of the Description, not including the
  Resolution field.

  [image]

Comment: Thank you!  I think the Enhanced Export will get us closest to what we are trying to achieve.