# Upload Excel to TFS, Issue for uploading the description info

Tags: excel, vba, tfs, export-to-excel

Try to upload the AZURE description to TFS,which is format of html,example
[image]

Is losing the HTML behavior and run to be plain text in TFS

As newbie in this field,I need your valuable input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This limitation is a known one.  Excel cannot render the text formats such as we saw in work item description field. Sorry for the inconvenience, appreciate your understanding.

With the latest Excel plugin, there is **a warning about losing the rich text formatting when *modifying* an HTML field**.

You could also take a look at this similar blog--[Work Items loosing formatting when edited in Microsoft Exce](https://hamidshahid.blogspot.com/2013/04/recently-we-upgraded-to-team-foundation.html)l.

As a workaround, you have to directly edit the description field to keep format in the web portal at present.

---

Besides, if you just want to export the description from TFS side and keep format, there's an extension called [Enhanced Export](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mskold.mskold-enhanced-export&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.vssps.visualstudio.com%2F_signedin%3Frealm), it is a web based solution that lets you export work item queries or test plans to document like formats. To get the output formatted the way you want, you can select different templates to get the form and layout of your choice. You can preview, print or even open the document directly in Office.

More details take a look at: [How to create a report in VSTS that collates work item descriptions/resolutions for easy readability?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52009946/how-to-create-a-report-in-vsts-that-collates-work-item-descriptions-resolutions/52015870#52015870) .